# Why It is giving me Integer Overflow

Tags: java, c

Its giving me Integer Overflow both in java and C but when I tried it in Python it gave me
right answer . Any reasons ?

```
long long int a = 1000000011/2 * 5 ;
printf("%lld",a);
```

Comment: in c/c++/java you need to use L suffix (or LL), like `1000000011L` to use long instead of integer during calculation

Comment: And in python integers can basically get as large as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. Most computer languages use fixed-size integers.  Today, that's often 32 bits.  The correct result of your calculation, 2500000025, is a 32-bit number, meaning it's too big for a *signed* 32-bit type.  (It comes out as -1794967271 in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).)  Python, on the other hand, is different: it uses [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).
2. In C, as in many computer languages, expressions are evaluated "inside out".  If you say `float f = 1 / 2;` you get 0, because the compiler performs integer division, without looking to see that you wanted to get a floating-point result.  If you say `long long int a = 1000000011/2 * 5;` you get an overflow, because the compiler performs integer arithmetic, without looking to see that you wanted to get a `long long` result.